# User Registered MFA Methods via MS Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This (legacy) PowerShell will display a user's MFA Methods.

```
$User = Get-MSolUser -UserPrincipalName Chad.Carlton@Contoso.com
$User.StrongAuthenticationMethods
```

(list of MFA methods)
(Columns for ExtensionData, IsDefault, MethodType)

What is the equivalent **MS Graph** API call?

I'm having a lot of trouble finding it on either the release or beta endpoints. I thought MS Graph parity with legacy api's was achieved.. maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Ms graph for User Registration MFA Methods is not supported. It is Under review. Please raise the [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or vote for similar [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20249953-powershell-and-graph-api-support-for-managing-mult)